# AFNetworking SSL Pinning

Tags: ios, https, openssl, ssl-certificate, afnetworking

> ```
>     Certificate chain
>  0 s:/OU=Domain Control Validated/OU=PositiveSSL Multi-Domain/CN=ssl279233.cloudflaressl.com
>    i:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO ECC Domain Validation Secure Server CA 2
> -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
> MIIHlDCCBzmgAwIBAgIRAPihThYIpoQha3AG/hNj9TcwCgYIKoZIzj0EAwIwgZIx
> CzAJBgNVBAYTAkdCMRswGQYDVQQIExJHcmVhdGVyIE1hbmNoZXN0ZXIxEDAOBgNV
> BAcTB1NhbGZvcmQxGjAYBgNVBAoTEUNPTU9ETyBDQSBMaW1pdGVkMTgwNgYDVQQD
> Ey9DT01PRE8gRUNDIERvbWFpbiBWYWxpZGF0aW9uIFNlY3VyZSBTZXJ2ZXIgQ0Eg
> MjAeFw0xNjAxMDUwMDAwMDBaFw0xNjEyMzEyMzU5NTlaMGwxITAfBgNVBAsTGERv
> bWFpbiBDb250cm9sIFZhbGlkYXRlZDEhMB8GA1UECxMYUG9zaXRpdmVTU0wgTXVs
> dGktRG9tYWluMSQwIgYDVQQDExtzc2wyNzkyMzMuY2xvdWRmbGFyZXNzbC5jb20w
> WTATBgcqhkjOPQIBBggqhkjOPQMBBwNCAASDqiHAaHhm92+X/4UZIUpMb2smkyRK
> MI175Kb2xEbOAFJASRFcbjwqb08lbShxn9AXWV4HKUlg52pEPPA5D/9Do4IFkzCC
> BY8wHwYDVR0jBBgwFoAUQAlhZ/C8g3FP3hIILG/U1Ct2PZYwHQYDVR0OBBYEFEe4
> ChCbKiqR1Ewb7KZyXF6A0k7OMA4GA1UdDwEB/wQEAwIHgDAMBgNVHRMBAf8EAjAA
> MB0GA1UdJQQWMBQGCCsGAQUFBwMBBggrBgEFBQcDAjBPBgNVHSAESDBGMDoGCysG
> AQQBsjEBAgIHMCswKQYIKwYBBQUHAgEWHWh0dHBzOi8vc2VjdXJlLmNvbW9kby5j
> b20vQ1BTMAgGBmeBDAECATBWBgNVHR8ETzBNMEugSaBHhkVodHRwOi8vY3JsLmNv
> bW9kb2NhNC5jb20vQ09NT0RPRUNDRG9tYWluVmFsaWRhdGlvblNlY3VyZVNlcnZl
> ckNBMi5jcmwwgYgGCCsGAQUFBwEBBHwwejBRBggrBgEFBQcwAoZFaHR0cDovL2Ny
> dC5jb21vZG9jYTQuY29tL0NPTU9ET0VDQ0RvbWFpblZhbGlkYXRpb25TZWN1cmVT
> ZXJ2ZXJDQTIuY3J0MCUGCCsGAQUFBzABhhlodHRwOi8vb2NzcC5jb21vZG9jYTQu
> Y29tMIID2gYDVR0RBIID0TCCA82CG3NzbDI3OTIzMy5jbG91ZGZsYXJlc3NsLmNv
> bYIYKi5hbnRpcXVlYWR2ZXJ0aXNpbmcuY29tggsqLmNjbm93LmNvbYITKi5jaGlj
> bG9jYXRpb25zLmNvbYIQKi5jai1qYWNrc29uLmNvbYIUKi5jb3Vyc2VjcnVzaGVy
> cy5jb22CESouZWNvc3lzdGVtaHEuY29tghUqLmZpZ2h0Y2Vuc29yc2hpcC5vcmeC
> FiouZ29ic21hY2tjb21pY3MuY28udWuCDiouZ29mdW5ib3guY29tgg4qLmdvZnVu
> Ym94Lm5ldIIOKi5nb2Z1bmJveC5vcmeCDCouaG92ZWxvLmNvbYITKi5sZXRtZXdh
> dGNodGhpcy5sdYIYKi5uZXdvcmxlYW5zbW9tc2Jsb2cuY29tghsqLm5pbnRlbmRv
> Zm9yY2VtYWdhemluZS5jb22CEyoubm9icm9rZW5kcmlwcy5jb22CDyoub3BlbnRl
> Y2guZnVuZIIgKi5wYXR0YXlhZ3Vlc3RmcmllbmRseWhvdGVscy5jb22CDCoucHJl
> aXNrLmNvbYIYKi5yYXBpZGFjdGlvbmNlbnRyYWwuY29tgg8qLnNvbGFybW92aWUu
> bHWCEyoudG9wc21hcmtldGluZy5jb22CDioudm9zY3JlZW4uY29tghgqLnlvdXJ0
> aXJlc2hvcHN1cHBseS5jb22CFmFudGlxdWVhZHZlcnRpc2luZy5jb22CCWNjbm93
> LmNvbYIRY2hpY2xvY2F0aW9ucy5jb22CDmNqLWphY2tzb24uY29tghJjb3Vyc2Vj
> cnVzaGVycy5jb22CD2Vjb3N5c3RlbWhxLmNvbYITZmlnaHRjZW5zb3JzaGlwLm9y
> Z4IUZ29ic21hY2tjb21pY3MuY28udWuCDGdvZnVuYm94LmNvbYIMZ29mdW5ib3gu
> bmV0ggxnb2Z1bmJveC5vcmeCCmhvdmVsby5jb22CEWxldG1ld2F0Y2h0aGlzLmx1
> ghZuZXdvcmxlYW5zbW9tc2Jsb2cuY29tghluaW50ZW5kb2ZvcmNlbWFnYXppbmUu
> Y29tghFub2Jyb2tlbmRyaXBzLmNvbYINb3BlbnRlY2guZnVuZIIecGF0dGF5YWd1
> ZXN0ZnJpZW5kbHlob3RlbHMuY29tggpwcmVpc2suY29tghZyYXBpZGFjdGlvbmNl
> bnRyYWwuY29tgg1zb2xhcm1vdmllLmx1ghF0b3BzbWFya2V0aW5nLmNvbYIMdm9z
> Y3JlZW4uY29tghZ5b3VydGlyZXNob3BzdXBwbHkuY29tMAoGCCqGSM49BAMCA0kA
> MEYCIQDtuNv9uln2jYTMAkrYQwRme8FHl7orN/FX03uQrIK0ZQIhAPR29giciodd
> 3DMcaoqSXvJoDB8SY0ieKwWvFXZoq+fZ
> -----END CERTIFICATE-----
>  1 s:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO ECC Domain Validation Secure Server CA 2
>    i:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO ECC Certification Authority
> -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
> MIIDnzCCAyWgAwIBAgIQWyXOaQfEJlVm0zkMmalUrTAKBggqhkjOPQQDAzCBhTEL
> MAkGA1UEBhMCR0IxGzAZBgNVBAgTEkdyZWF0ZXIgTWFuY2hlc3RlcjEQMA4GA1UE
> BxMHU2FsZm9yZDEaMBgGA1UEChMRQ09NT0RPIENBIExpbWl0ZWQxKzApBgNVBAMT
> IkNPTU9ETyBFQ0MgQ2VydGlmaWNhdGlvbiBBdXRob3JpdHkwHhcNMTQwOTI1MDAw
> MDAwWhcNMjkwOTI0MjM1OTU5WjCBkjELMAkGA1UEBhMCR0IxGzAZBgNVBAgTEkdy
> ZWF0ZXIgTWFuY2hlc3RlcjEQMA4GA1UEBxMHU2FsZm9yZDEaMBgGA1UEChMRQ09N
> T0RPIENBIExpbWl0ZWQxODA2BgNVBAMTL0NPTU9ETyBFQ0MgRG9tYWluIFZhbGlk
> YXRpb24gU2VjdXJlIFNlcnZlciBDQSAyMFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcD
> QgAEAjgZgTrJaYRwWQKOqIofMN+83gP8eR06JSxrQSEYgur5PkrkM8wSzypD/A7y
> ZADA4SVQgiTNtkk4DyVHkUikraOCAWYwggFiMB8GA1UdIwQYMBaAFHVxpxlIGbyd
> nepBR9+UxEh3mdN5MB0GA1UdDgQWBBRACWFn8LyDcU/eEggsb9TUK3Y9ljAOBgNV
> HQ8BAf8EBAMCAYYwEgYDVR0TAQH/BAgwBgEB/wIBADAdBgNVHSUEFjAUBggrBgEF
> BQcDAQYIKwYBBQUHAwIwGwYDVR0gBBQwEjAGBgRVHSAAMAgGBmeBDAECATBMBgNV
> HR8ERTBDMEGgP6A9hjtodHRwOi8vY3JsLmNvbW9kb2NhLmNvbS9DT01PRE9FQ0ND
> ZXJ0aWZpY2F0aW9uQXV0aG9yaXR5LmNybDByBggrBgEFBQcBAQRmMGQwOwYIKwYB
> BQUHMAKGL2h0dHA6Ly9jcnQuY29tb2RvY2EuY29tL0NPTU9ET0VDQ0FkZFRydXN0
> Q0EuY3J0MCUGCCsGAQUFBzABhhlodHRwOi8vb2NzcC5jb21vZG9jYTQuY29tMAoG
> CCqGSM49BAMDA2gAMGUCMQCsaEclgBNPE1bAojcJl1pQxOfttGHLKIoKETKm4nHf
> EQGJbwd6IGZrGNC5LkP3Um8CMBKFfI4TZpIEuppFCZRKMGHRSdxv6+ctyYnPHmp8
> 7IXOMCVZuoFwNLg0f+cB0eLLUg==
> -----END CERTIFICATE-----
>  2 s:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO ECC Certification Authority
>    i:/C=SE/O=AddTrust AB/OU=AddTrust External TTP Network/CN=AddTrust External CA Root
> -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
> MIID0DCCArigAwIBAgIQQ1ICP/qokB8Tn+P05cFETjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQwFADBv
> MQswCQYDVQQGEwJTRTEUMBIGA1UEChMLQWRkVHJ1c3QgQUIxJjAkBgNVBAsTHUFk
> ZFRydXN0IEV4dGVybmFsIFRUUCBOZXR3b3JrMSIwIAYDVQQDExlBZGRUcnVzdCBF
> eHRlcm5hbCBDQSBSb290MB4XDTAwMDUzMDEwNDgzOFoXDTIwMDUzMDEwNDgzOFow
> gYUxCzAJBgNVBAYTAkdCMRswGQYDVQQIExJHcmVhdGVyIE1hbmNoZXN0ZXIxEDAO
> BgNVBAcTB1NhbGZvcmQxGjAYBgNVBAoTEUNPTU9ETyBDQSBMaW1pdGVkMSswKQYD
> VQQDEyJDT01PRE8gRUNDIENlcnRpZmljYXRpb24gQXV0aG9yaXR5MHYwEAYHKoZI
> zj0CAQYFK4EEACIDYgAEA0d7L3XJghWF+3XkkRbUq2KZ9T5SCwbOQQB/l+EKJDwd
> AQTuPdKNCZcM4HXk+vt3iir1A2BLNosWIxatCXH0SvQoULT+iBxuP2wvLwlZW6Vb
> CzOZ4sM9iflqLO+y0wbpo4H+MIH7MB8GA1UdIwQYMBaAFK29mHo0tCb3+sQmVO8D
> veAky1QaMB0GA1UdDgQWBBR1cacZSBm8nZ3qQUfflMRId5nTeTAOBgNVHQ8BAf8E
> BAMCAYYwDwYDVR0TAQH/BAUwAwEB/zARBgNVHSAECjAIMAYGBFUdIAAwSQYDVR0f
> BEIwQDA+oDygOoY4aHR0cDovL2NybC50cnVzdC1wcm92aWRlci5jb20vQWRkVHJ1
> c3RFeHRlcm5hbENBUm9vdC5jcmwwOgYIKwYBBQUHAQEELjAsMCoGCCsGAQUFBzAB
> hh5odHRwOi8vb2NzcC50cnVzdC1wcm92aWRlci5jb20wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEMBQAD
> ggEBAB3H+i5AtlwFSw+8VTYBWOBTBT1k+6zZpTi4pyE7r5VbvkjI00PUIWxB7Qkt
> nHMAcZyuIXN+/46NuY5YkI78jG12yAA6nyCmLX3MF/3NmJYyCRrJZfwE67SaCnjl
> lztSjxLCdJcBns/hbWjYk7mcJPuWJ0gBnOqUP3CYQbNzUTcp6PYBerknuCRR2RFo
> 1KaFpzanpZa6gPim/a5thCCuNXZzQg+HCezF3OeTAyIal+6ailFhp5cmHunudVEI
> kAWvL54TnJM/ev/m6+loeYyv4Lb67psSE/5FjNJ80zXrIRKT/mZ1JioVhCb3ZsnL
> jbsJQdQYr7GzEPUQyp2aDrV1aug=
> -----END CERTIFICATE-----
> ```

When  I run openssl s_client -connect xxx:443 -showcerts
I got the response above.

I want to use ssl pinning with AFNetworking. Which certificate should I Use for SSL pinning I use the following function for settings for AFnetworking

```
+(AFSecurityPolicy*)setCertificateSettings
{

    AFSecurityPolicy* policy = [AFSecurityPolicy policyWithPinningMode:AFSSLPinningModePublicKey];

    [policy setValidatesDomainName:NO];
    [policy setAllowInvalidCertificates:YES];


    return policy;


}
```

Is this certificates .pem or .cer ? should i convert this certificates to a specific format.